# Invalid Bundle - Invalid Asset Catalog. One of the files named Assets.car is not a valid Asset Catalog file

Tags: ios, react-native, software-distribution

I have build a react-native app which I want to submit to Testflight.

I have tried a lot but keep getting this message:

Invalid Bundle - Invalid Asset Catalog. One of the files named Assets.car is not a valid Asset Catalog file.

It's very vague I don't know how to fix this.

Im running Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b) and macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29).

Full message from Apple after submitting to the App store.

```
Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Time". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Bundle - Invalid Asset Catalog. One of the files named Assets.car is not a valid Asset Catalog file

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know exactly what the problem was. I created a new project and copied some things over. I ditched CocoaPods and a GoogleVRKit library. After that I had no problems anymore.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I am using https://github.com/tiero/react-native-360 . I have created an issue in github https://github.com/tiero/react-native-360/issues/19. any solutions ?

Comment: Exactly I was using the exact same library! I also use react-native.